# Query that display father, son in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, tree

**I use MySQL**,

In my database, I have this table :

```
+-----------------------------+
| ID    NAME        ID_FATHER |
+-----------------------------+
| 1     Mylodi      0         |
| 2     Jack        0         |
| 3     Linda       1         |
| 4     Mark        2         |
| 5     Simon       4         |
| 6     Sacha       1         |
| 7     Edward      1         |
+-----------------------------+
```

By this query I retrieve each name with his father :

```
select f.name as father, s.name as son from family s, family f where s.id_father = f.id
```

**Result**

```
+------------+---------+
| father     | son     |
+------------+---------+
| mylodi     |  linda  |
| Jack       |  mark   |
| mark       |  simon  |
| mylodi     |  sacha  |
| mylodi     |  edward |
+------------+---------+
```

But, my question How can I get this result, but in one column like this :

```
+--------+
| colum  |
+--------+
| Mylodi |
| linda  |
| sacha  |
| edward |
| jack   |
| mark   |
| simon  |
+--------+
```

that mean I want to display the name of the Father and of below each name of father names of his son. Thanks.

**EDIT**
this is my db [structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aa0ac/1)

Comment: What have you tried? This is a fairly straightforward case of using the ORDER BY clause in a query.

Comment: with `Union` if you put your db structure in http://sqlfiddle.com/ we can help you better

Comment: This is a difficult problem, because it requires traversing a tree structure.  The exact mechanism for doing this depends on the database.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT id, name, id sort1, id_father sort2 FROM family WHERE id_father = 0
  UNION
  SELECT id, name, id_father, 1 sort2 FROM family WHERE id_father <> 0
) AS v 
ORDER BY sort1, sort2
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aa0ac/10).

Answer (score 0):

This is not so straightforward. It assumes that there are no loops in the data (a is b's father and b is a's father)

Not sure what database you are using, but Oracle has Hierarchical queries that are meant for problems like this using the "connect by" keyword.

Comment: I haven't personally done it, but there is are a number of posts on Hierarchical queries in MYSQL that you can search for.